# Trying to update CSV file with Java, but file size keeps increasing although the code empties its content

Tags: java, csv

I am coding with Java and I am trying to write in some forex data into a CSV file. I want the CSV file to be constantly the latest 277 datas without stacking on top of old data. So I used the "new FileWriter(file, false).close();" to empty the former data every time before the program writes in data. The code works as the newest Data starts always from index 1 in CSV opened with excel and the rest are blank. But the csv file size keeps increasing. Could anyone give me any ideas on how to modify the code so that the file size would not increase indefinitely?

```
        //this is the inside of a loop that starts every time a candle stick gets formed
        try {
            new FileWriter(file, false).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                console.getErr().println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(console.getErr());
                context.stop();
        }
        
        int shift = 1;
        while (shift < 278){
            
            IBar bar = history.getBar(Instrument.USDJPY, Period.FIVE_MINS, OfferSide.BID, shift);
            try {
                out.write(dateFormat.format(bar.getTime()) + "," + priceFormat.format(bar.getOpen()) + "," + priceFormat.format(bar.getHigh()) + ","
                        + priceFormat.format(bar.getLow()) + "," + priceFormat.format(bar.getClose()) + "," + priceFormat.format(askBar.getVolume()) + "\r\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                console.getErr().println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(console.getErr());
                context.stop();
            }
            
            shift+=1;
        }//while
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                console.getErr().println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(console.getErr());
                context.stop();
        }
```

Edit: I opened the CSV with notepad and saw an egregious amount of space and had to scroll far down to see the data. When I open properties of the CSV files, the size says 253 KB but the "size on disk" is 3.87 mb, which I don't understand. Anyway to solve this?

Edit2: Stopping the program on the Fx platform app from running presumably closed the Bufferwriter named "out" and the "size on disk" returns to normal. But still no idea on the space problem. Also somehow I can't manually edit it with notepad, it says I have no access to change the file when I attempt to save. I am new to programming so I don't know what did that either. Thank you.

Edit3: Solved it. The out.flush was the culprit, replaced it with out.close, and create a new bufferwriter named "out" every time this class gets started.

Comment: _"the csv file size keeps increasing"_ -- show us how you know this.  Does the file contain only the data you want, or do you see more lines in the file?  The question is a bit unclear at this point. Please read [ask] to learn what is expected of questions here.

Comment: This does not explain why the file size is increasing, but I would like to suggest using NIO.2 APIs if you are running a recent java version. it is easy to handle and will reduce boilerplate code

Comment: I checked it manually with file explorer. The CSV file increases by 20 KB or so every time it updates which is every 5 minutes.

Comment: @Prometheus666 - you are welcome to [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to your own question.